# Python. Extract delimeters separated data from line

Tags: python

I have text:

word1|word2|word3|||word4

what is the python code to create a line

word3|word4|

I wish it would be something like creating a line with variables x1,x2 , and then finding each variable like x1=text and | sign before third delimeter|  in the line, x2=text and | sign after fifth |delimeter in the line.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using simple expressions:

```
>>> s = "word1|word2|word3|||word4"
>>> xs = s.split("|")
>>> xs
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', '', '', 'word4']
>>> ys = filter(None, xs)
>>> ys
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']
>>> ss = "|".join(ys[2:])
>>> ss
'word3|word4'
>>>
```

1. split the list using `|` as the delimiter.
2. filter out falsey values (*e.g: `''`*)
3. join the 2nd element onwards with `|`

To get exactly the output you specified in your question you'll have to:

```
ss += "|"
```